# SELECT count(*) from where date(week number) equal to current week number

Tags: php, mysql, count, where-clause

I am using this to query from my table:

```
$res = $link -> query("SELECT count(*) FROM sales WHERE status='OK'") or die($mysqli->error);
$num_rows = mysqli_fetch_row($res)[0];
$numberOfSales = $num_rows;
```

In table `sales` I also have a column named date `datetime`.

I want it to only returns the number of rows where date is the same as the current week number. So if the date column cell has value `2020-08-03 16:25:26`, that converted to week number is 32.  I have been looking at `strftime("%V",`, but not sure how to proceed. Any tips?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

Consider and index-friendly expression such as:

```
select count(*) 
from sales 
where 
    status='OK' 
    and datetime >= current_date - interval weekday(current_date) day
```

Expression `current_date - interval weekday(current_date) day` dynamically computes the date that corresponds to the first day of the current week (starting on Monday).

If you may have dates in the future, then you can add an upper limit:

```
where 
    status='OK' 
    and datetime >= current_date - interval weekday(current_date) day
    and datetime <  current_date + interval (7 - weekday(current_date)) day
```

Comment: So I should just replace my code with your code inside the `$res = $link -> query("` that I have?

Comment: @Kama: yes, indeed.

Comment: I tried that, and in this code `$num_rows = mysqli_fetch_row($res)[0];` I get error: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in `.

Comment: @Kama: you need to recover the actual error message from mysql. Does the query work if you run it directly against the database (eg with phpmyadmin)?